# decoherency of number states

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-optics, decoherence

The meaning of decoherency is: When a nonclassical state, transitions to a classical state. It means that the state lost it's phase information. I can't understand how it happens in number states.

Comment: It's not a single state that loses the phase information but an ensemble of states. A quantum mechanical system is always a quantum mechanical system with a complex wave function, but if we look at the behavior of an ensemble of identical quantum mechanical systems, then we can talk about coherence (when the wave functions of all members of the ensemble are similar or equal in their phase) and decoherence (when they are not). Naively I don't see why this couldn't be applied to a number state, but I might be missing something.